# Remove link outline from p:tabView

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to remove the outline, when an user click on one of the [`<p:tabView>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml) tabs?

Set it in CSS did not help.

```css
a {
    outline: 0 none !important;
}
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Is the outline on the a? Or on another html element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outline is added to the `li` element because it picks up the `.ui-tabs-outline` class after being clicked on. You can override the `outline` property in the class instead:

```
li.ui-tabs-outline {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So easy and I did not see it :-/

Comment: You get used to reskinning PrimeFaces - it's sometimes easier to turn off the theme altogether.